# Facebook login with Cordova 2.7 and Android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm trying to connect to facebook trough my app via. a Cordova plugin, .. it works all fine, but I don't get a callback result..

Using this:
https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect

I have my "MainActivity" that implements "CordovaInterface"

And my plugin "FacebookConnect" that extends "CordovaPlugin"

I think my problem is that after the auth with facebook, its the "onActivityResult" method at the "MainActivity" that is called instead of the "FacebookConnect" plugin .. And I don't know why ..

Can anyone help with that?..

I hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh, finaly,.. I got it ...

The problem was that I was using the cordova embedding in my native app, and then I have to call

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallback;
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

After this it works perfect! ;)